# How to add a dropdown box for state name in vtiger crm

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

I have a form and I have to add state name field with a drop down so the user can select name of the state they want from that select box.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a databse like mysql.

- create a table `state` (`state_id`, `state_name`, `state_abbr`)
- fetch the states from the `state` table (write a function to fetch states)
- iterate in your option of the select box using php script, for example:

  ```
  <select name="state">
  <?php
  // At this point you should have a recordset $rsstate which fetches all the records from the state table
  while($rowState = mysql_fetch_array($rsState)) { ?>
      <option value=<?php echo $rowState["state_abbr"] ?>><?php echo $rowState["state_name"]; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
  ```

Comment: Thanks For Your reply......  Actually i have done this type of work in core PHP and i know how to do exactly but in Vtiger CRM it is very complex issue means of in which files we have to change so it comes properly at tpl file. so that is my problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can use vtlib library for that.

This how we create a state name dropdown Box in **Accounts** module using vtlib

```
<?php
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
$module = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Accounts');
$infoBlock = Vtiger_Block::getInstance('LBL_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION', $module);
$stateField = Vtiger_Field::getInstance('state', $module);
if (!$stateField) {
    $stateField = new Vtiger_Field();
    $stateField->name = 'state';
    $stateField->label = 'State';
    $stateField->columntype = 'VARCHAR(100)';
    $stateField->uitype = 16;
    $stateField->typeofdata = 'V~O';
    $infoBlock->addField($stateField);
    $stateField->setPicklistValues(array('Kerala', 'Karnataka', 'Maharashtra', 'Manipur'));

}
```

Add the rest of state list in that array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a databse like mysql.

- create a table state (state_id, state_name, state_abbr)
- fetch the states from the state table (write a function to fetch states)
- iterate in your option of the select box using php script
  example:

  ```
          <select name="state">
            <?php 
               *// At this point you should have a recordset $rsstate which fetches all the records from the state table*
              while($rowState = mysql_fetch_array($rsState)){?>
              <option value=<?php echo $rowState["state_abbr"]?>><?php echo $rowState["state_name"]; ?></option>
            <?php }?>
           </select>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to admin panel and add a picklist. Its very simple.